# Reading data from excel to populate a text field using auto complete in Jquery & PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-autocomplete, phpexcel

I have been working on JQuery & JQuery mobile and PHP to develop a mobile optimized website,i have come to an instance where I need to make my text field implement the Jquery auto-complete , also i need to fetch data from an excel sheet . Usually, PHP fetches data from MySql database but in my case i am fetching data from an excel sheet and i am just not able to figure this out? Any help will be appreciated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Howabout reading the excel into mysql on the first load of the excel so it can go from mysql in the future (faster). This class will handle that http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/files/ but I believe it only works for .xls and not .xlsx. Or is it that the user uploads the excel file each time?